# SSM Installed in aws instance but still cannot run shell command from boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have installed and running SSM in the Ubuntu EC2 instance I have. However, I am still getting the error.

This is my code:

```
ssm = boto3.client('ssm' ) 
commands = ['echo "hello world"']

ssm.send_command(DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript", Parameters={'commands': commands}, InstanceIds=['i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'])
```

Error:

> InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling
>   the SendCommand operation

Not being able to figure why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon EC2 SSM policy was not attached to the instance.

Comment: This managed policy `AmazonEC2RoleforSSM` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command:

```
aws ssm describe-instance-information --output text
```

to double check that your instance got the [SSM agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html) installed.

<sup>See also: [InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034797/55075).</sup>